# Dúvida com ViewBag, carregando informações para edição

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um erro, quando eu vou fazer um cadastro, eu carregado as informações desta forma:

```
//lista 
var tbuscarCategoria = new CadastroCategoriaAplicacao();
var listarCategoria = tbuscarCategoria.ListarTodos();
ViewBag.Categoria = new SelectList(listarCategoria, "IDCATEGORIA", "DESCRICAO");
```

Na edição do registro, eu preciso selecionar a categoria que esta no cadastro de cliente, neste ponto tenho um erro:

```
    public ActionResult AlteraRegistro(int id)
        {
            if (Session["id"] == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            try
            {

                var tbuscar = new CadastroClienteAplicacao();
                TB_CLIENTE tbCliente = tbuscar.ListarPorID(id);

                //lista 
                var tbuscarCategoria = new CadastroCategoriaAplicacao();
                var listarCategoria = tbuscarCategoria.ListarTodos();
                ViewBag.Categoria = new SelectList(listarCategoria, "IDCATEGORIA", "DESCRICAO",tbCliente.tbIDCATEGORIA.IDCATEGORIA);

                return View(tbCliente);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["Erro"] = "Erro ao Alterar Registro.";
                return RedirectToAction("ListarRegistro", "CadastroCliente");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Qual erro? Pode editar sua pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

O problema estava ocorrendo porque na minha classe em tinha uma integração com a tabela categoria:

```html
        [Display(Name = "Categoría:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
        public TB_CATEGORIA tbIDCATEGORIA { get; set; }
```

Fiz a alteração para pegar apenas o IDCATEGORIA do próprio cadastro:

```html
        [Display(Name = "Categoría:")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
        public int IDCATEGORIA { get; set; }
```

Para carregar os dados na view cadastro eu tenho:

```html
            var tbuscarCategoria = new CadastroCategoriaAplicacao();
            var listarCategoria = tbuscarCategoria.ListarTodos();
            ViewBag.Categoria = new SelectList(listarCategoria, "IDCATEGORIA", "DESCRICAO");
```

Na view

```html
            <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IDCATEGORIA)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.IDCATEGORIA, ViewBag.Categoria as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.IDCATEGORIA)
            </div>
```

Para carregar os dados na edição do cadastro eu tenho:

```html
                var tbuscar = new CadastroClienteAplicacao();
                TB_CLIENTE tbCliente = tbuscar.ListarPorID(id);

                //lista 
                var tbuscarCategoria = new CadastroCategoriaAplicacao();
                var listarCategoria = tbuscarCategoria.ListarTodos();
                ViewBag.Categoria = new SelectList(listarCategoria, "IDCATEGORIA", "DESCRICAO", tbCliente.IDCATEGORIA);
```

Isso resolveu o problema.